# What is the computational complexity of $Ax = b$ and $AX = B$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, computational-complexity

Suppose $A, A_i$ are $m\times m$-matrices, $x_i, b_i$ are $m \times 1$, $X$ and $B$ are $m \times n$-matrices.

What is the total computational burden of solving $A_ix_i = b_i$ for $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$ versus $AX = B$ (where we might assume $A_1 =A_2 = \dots A_n = A$).

Answer (score 0):

This is the general question of linear programming, and there are a number of works on the question. In short, linear programming is in P.

This is an older paper surveying some results: Megiddo, Nimrod. On the complexity of linear programming. IBM Thomas J. Watson Research Division, 1986. https://theory.stanford.edu/~megiddo/pdf/wcongres_4.0.a.pdf

Comment: (I assumed you were not asking how much longer it takes to solve N different problems as it does to solve 1. Obviously it takes approximately N times as long to solve N different problems as it does to solve 1.)

Comment: I am asking how much computation time can be saved by doing $AX=B$ vs solving it as n number of $Ax=b$. Is there any computational advantage?

Comment: The second way is MUCH more complex. In essence, the question you are asking is about the computational complexity of combining the answers to many $Ax=b$. I think, intuitively, that it will be roughly as high as solving $AX=B$, meaning all the computation you do to solve the individual equations is wasted - but I don't know how to show this.